# Cannot read module from ATL EMFTVM transformation in Java standalone project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-atl

According to the [ATL/EMFTVM wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATL/EMFTVM#Compiling_to_EMFTVM), `ATL/EMFTVM` can be run standalone by using

```
ResourceSet moduleRS = new ResourceSetImpl();
moduleRS.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(Resource.Factory.Registry.DEFAULT_EXTENSION, new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());

DefaultModuleResolver mr = new DefaultModuleResolver("pathToModuleDirectory", moduleRS);
TimingData td = new TimingData();
env.loadModule(mr, "ModuleName");
td.finishLoading();
env.run(td);
td.finish();
```

However, this always yields an exception saying `Module not found`. I debugged the code into great detail. Internally, a `SaxParseException` is thrown, which is weird since my **.emftvm file is not a XML file**. Any ideas how I can load the file properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I got the old version of EMFTVM, and have the same problem as you. I pull the latest version from github, and it is fine now.

Updates:
@dwagelaar, aha, yes, I used EMFTVMResourceFactoryImpl; Here is the code I used btw:

```
    ExecEnv env = EmftvmFactory.eINSTANCE.createExecEnv();
    ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSetImpl();
    rs.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("xmi", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
    rs.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("ecore", new EcoreResourceFactoryImpl());
    rs.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("emftvm", new EMFTVMResourceFactoryImpl());
```

Also, instead of passing a new ResourceSetImpl(as indicated in Wiki),

```
// Don't do this! 
ModuleResolver mr = new DefaultModuleResolver("platform:/plugin/my.plugin.id/transformations/", new ResourceSetImpl());
```

I passed in the **rs** object initialized above.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @user35443 Letian's provides a solution - pull the latest version, where the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This (still) does not work, because you would have to tell EMF that *.emftvm files are not XMI, and require the EMFTVMResourceFactoryImpl. The ATL/EMFTVM wiki page has been updated with improved code; see: https://wiki.eclipse.org/ATL/EMFTVM#Standalone_use

Comment: Can I have some help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196593/atl-transformation-rules-not-matching-nested-bpmn2-elements please? Many thanks